# sales_order table - increment_id doesn't match entity_id

Tags: magento2, sales-order, increment-id

I'm unsure whether they should match or not, I haven't been able to find a definitive answer yet.

The start of `sales_order` table looks fine:

[image]

But suddenly the `increment_id` column stopped matching the `entity_id` column:

[image]

The invoice IDs still match, `sales_invoice` table:

[image]

But maybe that's because we only have 103 invoices, whereas we have 270 orders. The IDs in the order table started to get out of sync at order 173.

Any help is greatly appreciated. We have multiple third party integrations, some of them use `entity_id` and some `increment_id`, so it gets very confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`increment_id` and  `entity_id` are two different elements at magento2.

`entity_id` is the primary key of the table which auto increment.

Where `increment_id`  an unique identifier of an order which  using build on some logic.

Like

```
Prefix
Suffix
Step
Start-value
Pad-length
```

That it logic is build at `Magento_SalesSequence` module. Please check more detail at https://www.classyllama.com/blog/m2-incrementid

Comment: Thanks, Amit. So if an API uses `entity_id` that is bad, correct? They should switch to `increment_id`? Do you know if `entity_id` should match `increment_id`?

Comment: use of `entity_id` is not bad. But use entity_id  and increment is totally depends on your business logic.If you want to  get order data using  increment id,then just  create  own api

Answer (score 0):

Your EntityID doesnt have to match your OrderID.

Your Ordernumbers are out of sync because of the quotation system behind magento. For every order a customer wants to make a quote gets created in your database and potentually reserving an ordernumber. Thats why the ordernumbers jump ( Invoice numbers wont jump ).

You can check that yourself on that MySql table:

```
quote
```

Comment: Hi. In `quote` I have 474 rows, and only `entity_id`. It increases by 1 for each quote. So there's about double the amount of quotes than orders. Currently the `entity_id` is four numbers behind `increment_id` in the `sales_order` table.